# Default splashscreen not replaced by custom one with Cordova

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

I have some trouble understanding the way splashscreen works with Cordova.

At the root of my project I have the folder "images", where I have my splashscreens (same level as "www", "platforms" , etc...).

I try to configure my project in order not to do manual operations in the "platform" directory.

Cordova is supposed to copy the files to the right folder in "platforms/andoird/res/drawable-*", isn't it?

My config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<platform name="android">
    ...
    <splash src="images/splashscreen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="images/splashscreen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="images/splashscreen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="images/splashscreen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="images/splashscreen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="images/splashscreen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="images/splashscreen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="images/splashscreen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    ...
</platform>
```

My plugin version :

```
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
```

My android version: 6.0.0

When I build and run my project, the splashscreen is the default one of cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating the version of the Android platform.

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your version of ionic. The res folder is not being properly configured. Run the following commands from the root of your project:

```
mv platforms/android/res/{values,xml} res
rm -rf platforms/android/res
cp -r res platforms/android
ionic build android
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use IONIC. I posted the resolution 14 days ago.